# python MySQLDb insert with prepared Statements

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-python

I have a table with fields

```
TABLE_PASTE(
      user_text longtext NOT NULL,
      number integer NOT NULL
 )
```

I am trying to insert a row in this table `TABLE_PASTE` from python using MySQLDb driver.

```
text="large_text"
value = 1
cursor.execute("Update TABLE_PASTE set user_text = ? where number = ?",(text,value))
```

Am getting this error

```
query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 11):

With `MySQLdb` you want to use **parameterized** (prepared statements technically don't exist in python) statements similar to string formatting in Python 2.x.

```
cursor.execute("Update TABLE_PASTE set user_text = %s where number = %s",(text,value))
```

Note that even though your `value` is an `int` you still must use `%s` to format it in your query.

You can find a good tutorial on `MySQLdb` [here](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/).

Comment: how to avoid sql injection in the above example?

Comment: Doesn`t work. For variable text='abc' which is a string cursor.execute appends extra ' single quotes like  cursor.execute("insert into table %s values %s", ('schema_name', 'ttt'))  gives error  Exception You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''source_schema_name' values 'ttt'' at line 1

Answer (score -7):

simply you can just use

```
cursor.execute("Update TABLE_PASTE set user_text = {} where number = {}" .format(text,value))
```

where format function will format your input accordingly whether its an int or a string!

Comment: You should not do this because it bypasses SQL escaping.

Comment: Direct string formatting of database statements with user input results in SQL injection vulnerabilities.  The other answer here using parameterized queries should result in proper quoting to avoid SQL injection.