# MySQL insert from a csv file

Tags: mysql, csv, python-3.x

I have a csv file I want to load into a database, but can't seem to have a row as a value for the insert function

```
for row in readCSV:

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO IPaddresses(Start) VALUES(row[0])")
```

I use the module pymysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're not using "load data [local] infile". It'd be much easier. Check out the command here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html and someone with a similar problem here [Python/MySQL - LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573009/python-mysql-load-data-local-infile)

Comment: is it still possible to do it the other way ?

Comment: @JesperPetersen If you're using MySQLDb, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128870/python-mysqldb-insert-with-prepared-statements

Answer (score 0):

What exactly happens when you run the code? Errors? Unexpected values in your table?